# How to get path of file or folder in the ftp server?

Tags: java

I am making a project which require to get the path of file or folder of shared folder of ftp server .

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the absolute path inside the FTP server of its shared folder, (a) you can't get it via FTP and (b) it wouldn't do you any good if you could. It's the shared folder. That's it. As far as you are concerned it is '/'.